# XSLT transformation: group and split file into parts

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am new to XSLT transformation and having very basic knowledge. 
I am looking for your help. I have an XML file please see sample below. I would like to split this file into multiple smaller files.

I would like to group based on value of cmfp:future and cmfp:quotation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<GuiRoot xmlns:cmfp="mx.MarketParameters.Fixing.Commodities.Futures" xmlns:mp="mx.MarketParameters" xmlns:fg="mx.MarketParameters.Fixing" xmlns:fgrt="mx.MarketParameters.Fixing.IRIndices" xmlns:xc="xmlCache" xmlns:fgfx="mx.MarketParameters.Fixing.FXIndices" xmlns:cmip="mx.MarketParameters.Commodities.Indices">
 <xc:XmlCache xc:action="Update">
  <xc:XmlCacheArea xc:value="MarketParameters">
   <mp:nickName xc:subset="Reference" xc:value="./BORATES">
    <mp:date xc:value="20161202">
     <fg:fixing>
      <cmfp:futurePrice>
       <cmfp:future xc:value="ONE">
        <cmfp:quotation xc:value="1.1">
         <cmfp:maturity xc:value="1.1.1">
          <cmfp:column xc:value="CLOSE" xc:type="Fields">
           <mp:HisValue xc:keyFormat="C">[startDate="19990101"][endDate="19990101"]13405.00</mp:HisValue>
          </cmfp:column>
         </cmfp:maturity>
        </cmfp:quotation>
       </cmfp:future>
       <cmfp:future xc:value="ONE">
        <cmfp:quotation xc:value="1.2">
         <cmfp:maturity xc:value="1.2.1">
          <cmfp:column xc:value="CLOSE" xc:type="Fields">
           <mp:HisValue xc:keyFormat="C">[startDate="19990101"][endDate="19990101"]13405.00</mp:HisValue>
          </cmfp:column>
         </cmfp:maturity>
        </cmfp:quotation>
        <cmfp:quotation xc:value="1.2">
         <cmfp:maturity xc:value="1.2.2">
          <cmfp:column xc:value="CLOSE" xc:type="Fields">
           <mp:HisValue xc:keyFormat="C">[startDate="19990101"][endDate="19990101"]13406.00</mp:HisValue>
          </cmfp:column>
         </cmfp:maturity>
        </cmfp:quotation>
       </cmfp:future>
       <cmfp:future xc:value="TWO">
        <cmfp:quotation xc:value="2.1">
         <cmfp:maturity xc:value="2.1.1">
          <cmfp:column xc:value="CLOSE" xc:type="Fields">
           <mp:HisValue xc:keyFormat="C">[startDate="19990101"][endDate="19990101"]13405.00</mp:HisValue>
          </cmfp:column>
         </cmfp:maturity>
        </cmfp:quotation>
       </cmfp:future>
       <cmfp:future xc:value="THREE">
        <cmfp:quotation xc:value="3.1">
         <cmfp:maturity xc:value="3.1.1">
          <cmfp:column xc:value="CLOSE" xc:type="Fields">
           <mp:HisValue xc:keyFormat="C">[startDate="19990101"][endDate="19990101"]13405.00</mp:HisValue>
          </cmfp:column>
         </cmfp:maturity>
        </cmfp:quotation>
       </cmfp:future>
       <cmfp:future xc:value="FOUR">
        <cmfp:quotation xc:value="4.1">
         <cmfp:maturity xc:value="4.1.1">
          <cmfp:column xc:value="CLOSE" xc:type="Fields">
           <mp:HisValue xc:keyFormat="C">[startDate="19990101"][endDate="19990101"]13405.00</mp:HisValue>
          </cmfp:column>
         </cmfp:maturity>
        </cmfp:quotation>
       </cmfp:future>
       <cmfp:future xc:value="EIGHT">
        <cmfp:quotation xc:value="8.1">
         <cmfp:maturity xc:value="8.1.1">
          <cmfp:column xc:value="CLOSE" xc:type="Fields">
           <mp:HisValue xc:keyFormat="C">[startDate="19990101"][endDate="19990101"]13405.00</mp:HisValue>
          </cmfp:column>
         </cmfp:maturity>
        </cmfp:quotation>
       </cmfp:future>
      </cmfp:futurePrice>
     </fg:fixing>
    </mp:date>
   </mp:nickName>
  </xc:XmlCacheArea>
 </xc:XmlCache>
</GuiRoot>
```

**Desired output**
***File1***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<GuiRoot xmlns:cmfp="mx.MarketParameters.Fixing.Commodities.Futures" xmlns:mp="mx.MarketParameters" xmlns:fg="mx.MarketParameters.Fixing" xmlns:fgrt="mx.MarketParameters.Fixing.IRIndices" xmlns:xc="xmlCache" xmlns:fgfx="mx.MarketParameters.Fixing.FXIndices" xmlns:cmip="mx.MarketParameters.Commodities.Indices">
 <xc:XmlCache xc:action="Update">
  <xc:XmlCacheArea xc:value="MarketParameters">
   <mp:nickName xc:subset="Reference" xc:value="./BORATES">
    <mp:date xc:value="20161202">
     <fg:fixing>
      <cmfp:futurePrice>
       <cmfp:future xc:value="ONE">
        <cmfp:quotation xc:value="1.1">
         <cmfp:maturity xc:value="1.1.1">
          <cmfp:column xc:value="CLOSE" xc:type="Fields">
           <mp:HisValue xc:keyFormat="C">[startDate="19990101"][endDate="19990101"]13405.00</mp:HisValue>
          </cmfp:column>
         </cmfp:maturity>
        </cmfp:quotation>
        <cmfp:quotation xc:value="1.2">
         <cmfp:maturity xc:value="1.2.1">
          <cmfp:column xc:value="CLOSE" xc:type="Fields">
           <mp:HisValue xc:keyFormat="C">[startDate="19990101"][endDate="19990101"]13405.00</mp:HisValue>
          </cmfp:column>
         </cmfp:maturity>
         <cmfp:maturity xc:value="1.2.2">
          <cmfp:column xc:value="CLOSE" xc:type="Fields">
           <mp:HisValue xc:keyFormat="C">[startDate="19990101"][endDate="19990101"]13406.00</mp:HisValue>
          </cmfp:column>
         </cmfp:maturity>
        </cmfp:quotation>
       </cmfp:future>
       <cmfp:future xc:value="FOUR">
        <cmfp:quotation xc:value="4.1">
         <cmfp:maturity xc:value="4.1.1">
          <cmfp:column xc:value="CLOSE" xc:type="Fields">
           <mp:HisValue xc:keyFormat="C">[startDate="19990101"][endDate="19990101"]13405.00</mp:HisValue>
          </cmfp:column>
         </cmfp:maturity>
        </cmfp:quotation>
       </cmfp:future>
      </cmfp:futurePrice>
     </fg:fixing>
    </mp:date>
   </mp:nickName>
  </xc:XmlCacheArea>
 </xc:XmlCache>
</GuiRoot>
```

***File2***
simlar to file 1 but different nodes based on mod result.....

***File3***
simlar to file 1 but different nodes based on mod result.....

Appriciate your help... thanks in advance

> **I tried with below XSLT code but its not giving me desired output....**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cmfp="mx.MarketParameters.Fixing.Commodities.Futures" xmlns:mp="mx.MarketParameters" xmlns:fg="mx.MarketParameters.Fixing" xmlns:fgrt="mx.MarketParameters.Fixing.IRIndices" xmlns:xc="xmlCache" xmlns:fgfx="mx.MarketParameters.Fixing.FXIndices" xmlns:cmip="mx.MarketParameters.Commodities.Indices" exclude-result-prefixes="cmfp mp fg fgrt xc fgfx cmip">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" standalone="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <!-- define variables  [start] -->
 <xsl:variable name="action" select="/GuiRoot/xc:XmlCache/@xc:action"/>
 <xsl:variable name="nickname" select="/GuiRoot/xc:XmlCache/xc:XmlCacheArea/mp:nickName/@xc:value"/>
 <xsl:variable name="mpdate" select="/GuiRoot/xc:XmlCache/xc:XmlCacheArea/mp:nickName/mp:date/@xc:value"/>
 <xsl:variable name="noOfSplits" select="3"/>
 <!-- define variables  [ end  ]-->
 <xsl:template match="cmfp:futurePrice">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="cmfp:futurePrice"/>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="cmfp:future" group-by="(position() -1) mod $noOfSplits">
   <xsl:variable name="file_name" select="format-number(current-grouping-key(),'000')"/>
   <xsl:result-document href="files/cmfp_SPLIT_{$file_name}.xml">
    <GuiRoot xmlns:cmfp="mx.MarketParameters.Fixing.Commodities.Futures" xmlns:mp="mx.MarketParameters" xmlns:fg="mx.MarketParameters.Fixing" xmlns:fgrt="mx.MarketParameters.Fixing.IRIndices" xmlns:xc="xmlCache" xmlns:fgfx="mx.MarketParameters.Fixing.FXIndices" xmlns:cmip="mx.MarketParameters.Commodities.Indices">
     <xc:XmlCache>
      <xsl:attribute name="xc:action">
       <xsl:value-of select="$action"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xc:XmlCacheArea xc:value="MarketParameters">
       <mp:nickName xc:subset="Reference">
        <xsl:attribute name="xc:value">
         <xsl:value-of select="$nickname"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <mp:date>
         <xsl:attribute name="xc:value">
          <xsl:value-of select="$mpdate"/>
         </xsl:attribute>
         <fg:fixing>
          <cmfp:futurePrice>
           <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
          </cmfp:futurePrice>
         </fg:fixing>
        </mp:date>
       </mp:nickName>
      </xc:XmlCacheArea>
     </xc:XmlCache>
    </GuiRoot>
   </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what are the criteria for splitting? Why does the first result file have `cmfp:future xc:value="ONE"` and `cmfp:future xc:value="FOUR"` but then there are two different files for the `TWO` and `THREE` values?

Comment: Thanks Martin. I just realised I gave wrong input file. Basically I need to group based on cmfp:future and cmfp:quotation. I used simple mod function based on node position....

Comment: In example uniq cmfp:future are ONE, TWO, THREE , FOUR and EIGHT i.e. total 5 uniq values. If I choose mod function ONE & FOUR will be in same file. TWO and EIGHT in same file and THREE will be in seperate file. Hope it clarifies. thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you first need to group and then you can split based on position, the following is an attempt with XSLT 3.0 (as supported by Saxon 9.8 (all editions) or 9.7 PE and EE):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xpath-default-namespace="mx.MarketParameters.Fixing.Commodities.Futures"
    xmlns:xc="xmlCache"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="noOfSplits" select="3"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="original-root-element" select="*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="groups">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="//future" group-by="@xc:value">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/quotation" group-by="@xc:value">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="@*, current-group()/node()"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$groups/future" group-by="(position() - 1) mod $noOfSplits">
          <xsl:result-document href="split{position()}.xml">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$original-root-element">
                <xsl:with-param name="contents" select="current-group()" tunnel="yes"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="futurePrice">
        <xsl:param name="contents" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$contents"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To run it with an XSLT 2.0 processor like older Saxon 9 versions you have to spell out the identity transformation shallow copy with e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

instead of using the `xsl:mode`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Martin Honnen